# Help reading music sheet

Tags: notation, sheet-music, composition, sight-reading

[image]

Could someone help me explain this music sheet of Frere Jacque?

The is a Violin key, A mole on the A line and some notes. What do I habe to do with them in order to play this the correct way according to how it is specifically written on the picture ‍♂️

Comment: Apart from the barlines missing and the flat (and lower 4, but that hardly matters) lower than it should be, I don't see anything wrong with it, and certainly not anything complicated about it either. If you know the basics of reading sheet music, you shouldn't have any trouble at all.

Comment: Is this a question about how to read music, or how to play the violin? Or are you confused by some detail in particular?

Answer (score 2):

First, some English-language music terminology:

- <s>violin key</s> -> treble clef
- <s>mole</s> -> flat
- <s>A line</s> -> A space

So it is a treble clef with a flat on the A space.  That is a mistake.  If a key signature has a single flat symbol, it is always on B.  Such a key signature indicates either F major or D minor<sup>*</sup>, and we can see that the notes are those for Frère Jacques in F major.  Thus we can conclude that the placement of the flat symbol is erroneous.

Also, the last note should be a half note (also known as a minim) rather than a quarter note (a.k.a crotchet).

---

* Exceptions are possible, but they are beyond the scope of the basic music theory needed to identify this error.

Comment: 'If a key signature has a single flat symbol, it is always on B'. Normally, and should be, true! I used to work with a band where the sharps/flats were any old where. it didn't really matter, as for example, 3# must indicate A, and we all know which those # are, I hope!

Comment: @Tim maybe one of your old band mates produced the notation in this question!

Comment: @phoog Or maybe they studied #10 from the first book of [Bartók's Mikrokosmos](https://imslp.eu/files/imglnks/euimg/1/1b/IMSLP01109-Bartok_microcosmos_Book1.pdf) :-)